# Prove that if $f(x)=a/(x+b)$ then $f((x_1+x_2)/2)\le(f(x_1)+f(x_2))/2$

Tags: functions

This exercise :

> If  $f(x)=a/(x+b)$ then : $$ f((x_1+x_2)/2)\le(f(x_1)+f(x_2))/2$$

was in my math olympiad today (for 16 years olds). 
I proved this by saying this is true due to Jensen's inequality.

Is this an acceptable answer?(with leaving aside  the fact that i didn't prove the function is convex since it can't be done with the info we got until now).
Does it have any other way of proving this?

Comment: In questions like this, you should be more careful with your statement of the problem. What are the allowed values of $x$, $a$, and $b$? Obviously there must be restrictions $-$ for instance, if $x = -b$, then $f(x)$ is not defined; and if $a < 0$, then the statement is false.

Comment: x is from  -b to  $ \infty $

Comment: No, you have to do better than that. You don't say whether $x$ is allowed to be equal to $b$; and you don't give any restrictions on $a$. Surely the exam question had these details?

Comment: yes it had those

Comment: $ ]-b;+ \infty[ $

Comment: I give up.${}{}$

Answer (score 2):

I'll use $x$ and $y$ instead of $x_1,x_2$ .

You can just calculate and see what you get  :

$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \left (\frac{a}{x+b}+\frac{a}{y+b} \right )>\frac{2a}{2b+x+y}$$

$$\frac{1}{x+b}+\frac{1}{y+b} \geq \frac{4}{x+y+2b}$$

You can prove this by a simple calculation :

$$\frac{(x-y)^2}{(x+b)(y+b)(x+y+2b)} \geq 0$$ which is obvious .

You can also prove it by Cauchy-Schwarz in a special form :

$$\frac{1}{x+b}+\frac{1}{y+b} \geq \frac{(1+1)^2}{x+y+2b}=\frac{4}{x+y+2b}$$

Comment: is it wrong to say this is true due to jensen's inequality?

Comment: @KristianMihalaj   It isn't but you must prove that $f$ is convex .

Answer (score 1):

You can prove that f is convex by finding it second derivative, which is positive.